# String replacement in a large text file

Tags: string-manipulation

I have to replace a string, let's say `"ABC"` to `"XYZ"`, in a huge plain text file (10 Gb and above). Obviously, the `Import[]` and `StringReplace[]` approach is unfeasible so I'm trying a char-by-char processing inside a `While[]` loop, but
this coarse method is, as one would expect, extremely slow. Can you, please, suggest any smarter algorithm or method?

Comment: Used sed instead of mathematica, that's what I do when I have large files.  Just type in the terminal `sed -i 's/ABC/XYZ/g' filename.txt > newfile.txt` That's assuming you have a unix computer though.

Comment: if you must use mathematica for this, process in blocks with something like: `ReadList[file, "Character", blocksize]` in a loop.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use Mathematica for this? If not, what OS do you use?

Comment: @george2079 It's not so easy as that. What happens when the search string happens to lie on the border of two blocks?

Comment: Right, you need to look at two blocks at a time to catch strings on the border (I didn't say it was easy !)

Comment: "Is there a specific reason why you need to use Mathematica for this?" I must use Mathematica for this because it's a step of a larger computation. "It's not so easy as that. What happens when the search string happens to lie on the border of two blocks?"  
"Right, you need to look at two blocks at a time to catch strings on the border (I didn't say it was easy !)" That's precisely the problem I got stuck in.

Comment: @mitochondrial In the past I've chained steps involving bash, MATLAB, python, perl and some custom binaries written in C/C++ with Mathematica to create a complex workflow that's managed entirely within Mathematica. Please look at `Run` and `RunProcess` (v10+ only) for how to run external programs from _Mathematica_. In your current task, this might've been a step that's easily replicable in Mathematica, but what if you need to use a custom binary for some specialized task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit take 2: this turns out bit cleaner. As we read each block look for characters at the end that *might be* the beginning of a match and push those to the next block.

```
Export["test.txt", input = "manmanman"]
infile = OpenRead["test.txt"];
outfile = OpenWrite["out.txt"];
subs = "man" (* strings only, no string expressions *)
repl = "woman"
block = 5;  (*for practical use this should be as large as memory permits*)

potentialendmatch[blockdata_, substr_] := Module[{
   npush = Min[{StringLength[substr] - 1, StringLength[blockdata]}],
   (*this tmp replacement takes care of cases where substr occurs in
     blockdata near the end and contains its own beginning
     eg blockdata="xxxabab" substr="aba" : dont push the trailing "ab"*)
   tmps = StringReplace[blockdata,
     substr -> StringReplace[substr, _ -> FromCharacterCode[0]]]},
   While[ StringTake[tmps, -npush] =!=
     StringTake[substr, npush] && npush > 0 , --npush]; npush]

currentblock = StringJoin@ReadList[infile, "Character", block]
While[ StringLength@currentblock != 0 ,
  npush = potentialendmatch[StringTake[currentblock,
      -Min[StringLength@currentblock, (2 StringLength@subs - 1)]], 
           subs];
  If[npush < StringLength@currentblock,
   WriteString[outfile, StringReplace[
     StringTake[currentblock, {1, -npush - 1}]  , subs -> repl]]];
  currentblock = StringJoin[
    StringTake[currentblock, -npush],
    StringJoin@ReadList[infile, "Character", block]];
  ];
Close /@ {infile, outfile}
Import["out.txt"]
```

> "womanwomanwoman"

Comment: I don't think this works correctly. I used "manmanman" as input, block=5 and plen=4 and want to replace "man" with "woman". Output: womanmanw and not "womanwomanwoman" as expected.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries good catch, as-is the replacement needs to be the same length. I'm afraid fixing that using this framework will get really cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for your erudite reply. I'm studying it in details, but I find it a bit complex. Please, can you produce any guidance about the "flow chart" ?

Comment: hold tight, trying to think how to fix the string length issue.